# How do I sort by predicted probability in a binary classifer?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I trained a binary classifier and can get a good score.

```
reviews['prediction'] = model.predict(reviews.review.astype(str))
model.score(reviews.review.astype(str), reviews.sentiment)
model.predict_proba(reviews.review.astype(str))
```

I get the probability in an array when I print the predict_prob

```
array([[ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0.7,  0.3],
       ..., 
       [ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ]])
```

How do I take the highest probability and append it to the data frame just like I did with the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `max(axis=1)` on the array to get the maximum value of each row, for example:

```
reviews['proba'] = predict_prob.max(axis=1)
```